# how to update the specific "NO-NorthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk" into MagistratesEnquiries@justice.gov.uk using robo 3t 1.3:

Tags: mongodb-query, robo3t

[{
"EmailAddress" : "NO-NorthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "NO-NorthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "NO-NorthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "NO-NorthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}]

[{
"EmailAddress" : "MagistratesEnquiries@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "MagistratesEnquiries@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "MagistratesEnquiries@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}
{
"EmailAddress" : "MagistratesEnquiries@justice.gov.uk, NO-SouthNorthumbria@justice.gov.uk.cjsm.net, cdnenforcement@justice.gov.uk",
}]